# How pods are able to mount the same pvc with ReadWriteOnce access mode when storageClass is with glusterfs but not with cinder default storage?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

Want to understand how pod1 claimed PVC with `accessMode: ReadWriteOnce` is able to share with pod2 when `storageclass glusterfs` is created?Shouldn't it fail as I need to specify the `accessMode` as `ReadWriteMany`?

-> Created `storageclass` as `glusterfs` with `type:distributed`

-> PV created on top of the `storageclass` above and pvc is done with `AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce`

-> First Pod attached the above PVC created

-> Second Pod trying to attach the same PVC created and it does work and able to access the files which first pod created

Tried another flow without a `storageclass` and directly creating PVC from the cinder storage and the below error shows up,

`Warning  FailedAttachVolume  28s   attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-644f3e7e-8e65-11e9-a43e-fa163e933531" Volume is already used by pod(s) pod1`

Trying to understand why this is not happening when the `storageclass` is created and assigned to PV?

How I am able to access the files from the second pod when the `AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce`?
According to k8s documentation if multiple pods in different nodes need to access it should be ReadWriteMany.

If `RWO` access mode works then is it safe for both the pods to read and write? Will there be any issues?
What is the role of `RWX` if `RWO` works just fine in this case?

Would be great if some experts can give an insight into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Volumes are `RWO` per node, not per Pod. Volumes are mounted to the node and then bind mounted to containers. As long as pods are scheduled to the same node, `RWO` volume can be bind mounted to both containers at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The pods are running in different nodes actually in the above test which I mentioned. Found this bug report meanwhile - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60903 not sure if this is a bug now or it's just how it works.

Comment: @MelwynJensen as they haven't come to a decision regarding this issue, I suppose it depends on who you ask. In my personal book, this would likely be a bug, as it's just too dangerous to let it happen and for those who specifically want to share the volume, they would be better served by `RWX` or by some other mode that doesn't exist, yet, in my opinion.

Comment: @Tuminoid, I found out this is not a case for EFS type of storage class.
Pod replicas (controlled by Deployment) are scheduled evenly on all nodes, and processes inside them are able to write to the same shared file simultaneously, in spite the fact their use PVC with accessModes:  ReadWriteOnce.